# Create Empty DataFrame from list is x4 times slower than from emptyRDD()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We want to create an empty DataFrame at some point in our code. We have found this weird issue.

---

When creating from an empty list, this slows down our program, and causes every spark action (e.g. df.write()) later on in the program to be 4x times slower:

`spark.createDataFrame([], schema)`

After lots of debugging, I've found this to solve the issue:

`spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema)`

---

Tried to look at Spark source code, but couldn't get to any conclusion.
Also, did df.explain() to DataFrames in the program - but the plans are identical.
My only though is that the 1st option causes some extra communication with the worker nodes.

Does anyone knows why the 1st option is much slower than the 2nd?

Comment: why collect? not wise

Comment: @thebluephantom I meant that every action that causes a collect (write/show, etc...) is much slower. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()` creates an RDD with zero partitions, while `spark.createDataFrame([], schema)` creates a DataFrame with at least one partition.
The overhead is due to tasks on empty partitions.